# Efficient algorithm to get node in a subset most connected to nodes in another subset in a directed graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I need an efficient way to find the node in a subset of nodes that is the most connected to another subset of nodes.

Currently, I iterate over each node in the first subset S1 and increment a counter if there is a path to a node in subset S2, done over each node in S2. So time complexity is S1xS2x(time to find a path between candidates). My current algorithm is implemented using networkx and the graph is a directed graph.

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first subset is connected ( there is a path between every pair of nodes  in the subset ) then there is no answer, all nodes are equally connected to the second subset..  If your second subset is connected, then again there is no answer because every node is equally connected, or not.

If your subsets are not connected, then the "most connected" node in the first subset is one of the nodes in the first subset connected to the largest component of the second subset. ( A component is a set of nodes, all reachable from each other )

So:

```
If subsets are connected
    select random node
If second subset not connected
    find largest component of second subset
    find first node in first subset connected to node in largest component of second sebset.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I slowly getting the intuition, but can you define the largest component?

Comment: Just discovered that there's a thing called component in graph theory. Thanks for the tip!